# NSTable scroll automatically when i select a row from code in osx

Tags: cocoa, nstableview

I have a table with a lot of rows (means that i should scroll to see last rows),i select row from code with below code and i want to write code that table scroll automatically and show selected row to me .

```
int currentIndex=..;
NSIndexSet *index=[NSIndexSet indexSetWithIndex:currentIndex];
[self.tbl selectRowIndexes:index byExtendingSelection:YES];
```

i use `displayRect` like below for table but doesn't work

```
[self.tbl displayRect:NSMakeRect(0, currentIndex*30, self.tbl.frame.size.width, self.tbl.frame.size.height)];
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try `scrollRowToVisible: row`

Cheers

Answer (score 1):

You should use the NSTableView method, scrollRowToVisible: